# How to set WebStorm for node.js?

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm developing for ReactNative because I developer of front-end. (Using WebStorm)

But I got a job of server of node.js. (I want to using WebStorm too)

[image]

A lot of expression is occurrence like this.

I just clone some node.js project and open the project in WebStorm.

How do I set WebStorm for node.js? 
(if I change setting for node.js, I wish ReactNative project is not changed.)

Comment: Official documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/developing-node-js-applications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that **JavaScript Language Version** (**Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript**) is set to `ECMAScript 6`; looks as if ESMAScript 6 syntax (arrow functions, etc.) can't be parsed correctly